# How do I create an AngularJS tooltip directive with a compiled template?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, tooltip

I've searched the internet long and hard and found no straight answer. My question is simple, I want to have something like this in my markup:

```
<div my-tooltip-template="'mytt.tpl.html'" my-tooltip-scope="myDataItem">Some text...</div>
```

**EDIT:** Where `myDataItem` is a scope variable which contains my data object, and with a template which might look like:

```
<h1>{{dataItem.title}}</h1>
<span>{{dataItem.description}}</span>
```

And I want to have that template compiled with the a scope which contains `myDataItem` as `dataItem` and displayed as a tooltip. As far as I could tell by experimenting with `ui-bootstrap` `tooltip` module, the way to inject html into a tooltip is by using the directive `tooltip-html-unsafe` but the html injected doesn't get compiled, i.e., angular expressions are not evaluated, directives are not expanded, etc.

How do I go about creating a directive for this? I want a lean result, I don't want to have to include jQuery or any other library, just AngularJS and ui-bootstrap.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - are you trying to create your own tooltip with customizable template, and not use ui-bootstrap's?

Comment: why to reinvent the wheel? you can download only modules which you actually need and the tooltip module is only 4.7 kb large.

Comment: The tooltip module doesn't allow for compiled templates... Unless I'm missing something (on and I'm definitely not trying to reinvent the wheel, but I don't want my codebase to get bloated unnecessarily)

Comment: @NewDev can ui-bootstrap's tooltip achieve what I'm aiming for in that html snippet I posted? Either as is or with writing my own directive on top of it?

Comment: Where will "Some text..." go?

Comment: @NewDev Some text... is what is displayed on the page, when you hover over it, a tooltip appears with the compiled template and scope specified.

Comment: Ah, ok... I thought that it becomes the content of the tooltip.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here're the blueprints of how you could create a tooltip according to your requirements (or modify/encorporate this with ui-bootstrap's tooltip).

```
app.directive("myTooltipTemplate", function($compile){
  var contentContainer;
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {
      myTooltipScope: "="
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, linker){
      var templateUrl = attrs.myTooltipTemplate;

      element.append("<div ng-include='\"" + templateUrl + "\"'></div>");
      var toolTipScope = scope.$new(true);
      angular.extend(toolTipScope, scope.myTooltipScope);
      $compile(element.contents())(toolTipScope);
    }
  };

});
```

This, of course, doesn't have any of the actual tooltip functionality, like popup, placement, etc... - it just appends the compiled template to whatever the element that this directive applies to.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EbXfzPZDdMv9b4S8S63M?p=preview)

Changed [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/444UiYYqbwUGdcMKwKPg?p=preview) with closer-to-tooltip behavior;

Comment: Ok, so now how do I make it into an actual tooltip? :) The thing is, i don't have an element to apply your directive to, or rather I do, but that element doesn't get compiled so the directive doesn't get expanded...

Comment: I don't understand. The question was to apply it to some `<div>`. Are you saying that this div is dynamically created and thus this directive is not being compiled? This is a different issue, isn't it?

Comment: I want `Some text...` to appear on the page, and when hovered on, a tooltip appears with the content of a template compiled with a scope... the `my-tooltip-*` attributes relate to the tooltip of the `div` not the `div` itself.

Comment: Forked the original [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/444UiYYqbwUGdcMKwKPg?p=preview). The rest is up to you :)

Comment: Ok this is very nice, and I can adapt it to my use, but one more question, can I have it use `ui-bootstrap` tooltip apearance and placement? If not, then that's ok too, I will mess with that myself.

Comment: Not trivially so... tooltip directive creates another directive that hosts the actual tooltip (this is what @Dylan changed to point to a different `templateUrl`) with a $tooltip service, as it seems. There's no hook, as I can see it, to have pass any kind of parameter, including the dynamic Url of the template.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63578/discussion-between-aviad-p-and-new-dev).

Comment: Thank you for this... I was looking for something lightweight with no dependencies... just to make it happen with a few lines of code and this is perfect.

Comment: This is very slow when running more than 1000 tooltips. Is there any way fasten this?

Answer (score 7):

I was able to just copy and override the directive for the tooltip-html-unsafe

```
angular.module( 'ui.bootstrap.tooltip')
.directive( 'tooltipSpecialPopup', function () {
    return {
     restrict: 'EA',
     replace: true,
     scope: { content: '@', placement: '@', animation: '&', isOpen: '&' },
     templateUrl: 'tooltip.tpl.html'
  };
})

.directive( 'tooltipSpecial', [ '$tooltip', function ( $tooltip ) {
     return $tooltip( 'tooltipSpecial', 'tooltip', 'mouseenter' );
 }]);
```

I just changed the unsafe bit to special in the directive name and changed the template.

**Here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9rnZw0AArn76LjokFSi5?p=preview)**

Comment: Hi this does not actually compile the tooltip template, see the edited plunker for an example http://plnkr.co/edit/RKaSiw01pcGK7yxp797P?p=preview

Comment: Sure, in this scenario you would have to push your data through with @content,  we're limited by this part here -  https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/tooltip/tooltip.js#L98 -  the actual template is hardcoded.

Comment: Can I edit that template to have an `ng-include` directive then, with my desired scope? If so, how?

Comment: Even though this answer (with the accompanying comments) suggests a more complete solution, it involves changing library code, so I am going to accept the other answer since it does meet my requirements, albeit without the benefit of relying on the `bootstrap` `tooltip` package. However I am voting this one up.

Comment: @Dylan i have the same case but the templateUrl is dynamic how doing ?

Answer (score 2):

I found this question searching for a classic tooltip implementation in AngularJS, jQuery (and other libraries) free.

I have built the following directive if anyone is searching for one:

```
app.directive('tooltip', function($sce, $compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            content: '=tooltipContent'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attributes) {

            /* Attributes */

            scope.displayTooltip = false;

            /* Methods */

            scope.updateTooltipPosition = function(top, left) {
                tooltip.css({
                    top: top + 'px',
                    left: left + 'px',
                });
            };

            scope.getSafeContent = function(content) {
                return $sce.trustAsHtml(content);
            };

            /* Bootstrap */

            var tooltip = angular.element(
                '<div ng-show="displayTooltip" class="tooltip">\
                    <span ng-bind-html="getSafeContent(content)"></span>\
                </div>'
            );

            angular.element(document.querySelector('body')).append(tooltip);

            /* Bindings */

            element.on('mouseenter', function(event) {
                scope.displayTooltip = true;
                scope.$digest();
            });

            element.on('mousemove', function(event) {
                scope.updateTooltipPosition(event.clientY + 15, event.clientX + 15);
            });

            element.on('mouseleave', function() {
                scope.displayTooltip = false;
                scope.$digest();
            });

            /* Compile */

            $compile(tooltip)(scope);
        }
    };
});
```

You can test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/m4sr9jmn/2/

Hope it will help !