# Is it possible to create a tooltip of directive in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, tooltip

Hi is it possible to create a tooltip of which the content is an AngularJS directive? Meaning that the tooltip contains not only texts (like a normal tooltip), but some SVG graphs as well. The use case will be the same, say, the user mouses-over an element, and instead of showing some texts, it's now showing some graphs.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26541864/how-do-i-create-an-angularjs-tooltip-directive-with-a-compiled-template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use angular-bootstrap popover directive with custom template. You can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16722424/how-do-i-create-an-angularjs-ui-bootstrap-popover-with-html-content)