# Angularjs: Directive With Bootstrap Tooltip

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Hey guys want to create a new directive that  when you have any tag with attribute bt-tooltip=”your message goes here” it should add bootstrap tooltip to the element. The tooltip message should have a !!! at the end of message.

(e.g. This is a paragraph

should show a tooltip with message “This is a tooltip!!!”

or

List item should show a tooltip with message “Second tooltip!!!”)

I can easily add tooltip via bootstrap but want to add it like description above.especialy the part that you get the input from attribute like this `<p bt-tooltip=”This is a tooltip”>`

Right now my angular code looks like this

```
 app.directive("bttooltip", function() {
      return {
          template : "<p>Made by a directive!<p>"

     };
 });
```

What should i do?

Comment: I still recommend using UI Bootstrap, but I've updated my answer to show how you can use a directive if you prefer. It requires jQuery (as opposed to the jqLite included with Angular).

Answer (score 2):

There's a much easier way to use bootstrap stuff with Angular: [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), written by the Angular team and allows the use of bootstrap as directives - no jQuery (besides the minimal version included with Angular) required. Once you set a script reference to the Angular UI library (be sure to use the "tpls" version to get all the styled templates) and a reference to the boostrap CSS you can do this:

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap'])
.controller('mainController', function(){
    var _this = this;
    _this.toolTip = 'Here is a sample tooltip';
})

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainController as main" style="padding: 100px;">
    <button uib-tooltip="{{main.toolTip}}!!!">
    Button with a Tooltip
    </button>
</div>
```

[Here's a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/13z2xsqd/) demonstrating the above.

**Update**

If you still want to use your directive, try changing it to this:

```
app.directive("btTooltip", function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            $timeout(function() {
                $(element).data("title", attrs.btTooltip + "!!!");
                // set other options via data or use an options object
                $(element).tooltip();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.i will try it.it would be better for other people if you replace new answer with the old fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
element.append("<div ng-include='\"" + templateUrl + "\"'></div>");
```

check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26541864/how-do-i-create-an-angularjs-tooltip-directive-with-a-compiled-template)

Comment: i don't want to include a template.just a simple attribute.