# how to use twitter bootstrap javascript component in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use tootltip of twitter bootstrap in my angularjs web app. when I use them simply in my code and put the jQuery initialization on top of my js file inside `document.ready` it works perfectly.

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    $(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
    });
    $('.myslider').myslider();
});

var myapp = angular.module("eplApp",['ui.router']);
```

but when I use them in view by ui-routing. It stops working with no error in console..
i am also using more javascript components like crousel. I would like to know how to intialize/call them in view ad document.ready doesn't work in views.

should I initialize them in my controller.
if yes than how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angularjs: Directive With Bootstrap Tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711703/angularjs-directive-with-bootstrap-tooltip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use Bootstrap UI in Angular, it would be a better idea to use Angular Module `ui.bootrap` found [here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#top)

While you can always create your own angular directives for bootstrap tooltips, this is a quicker way out.

```
var myapp = angular.module("eplApp",['ui.router','ui.bootstrap']);
```

and in your HTML

```
<button tooltip-placement="{{placement.selected}}" uib-tooltip="On the {{placement.selected}}" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Tooltip text</button>
```

Changing routes using `ui.router` will not fire `$document.ready()` again. If the state is loaded after `$doucment.ready()` is called, your code will not work. If you do not wish to include `ui.bootstrap`, create a directive and initialize tooltip using `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()` in the link function of your directive.