# How to render custom directive inside ui-bootstrap tooltip

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have following code

// Template

```
<span>
    hello world!
</span>
```

// Directive

```
'use strict';

var referenceFieldTemplate = require('./reference-field.html');

module.exports = directiveFunction;

/* @ngInject */
function directiveFunction($http) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      fieldName: '=',
      fieldValue: '='
    },
    templateUrl: referenceFieldTemplate,
    controller: function($scope){
      console.log($scope);
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      element.bind('mouseover',function(e) {
        console.log(e);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to render custom directive in uib-tooltip using following code

```
function eventRender(event, element, view) {
    var hoverMarkup = '\'<reference-field field-name="test" field-value="test"></reference-field>\''
    element.attr({
      'uib-tooltip-html': hoverMarkup,
      'tooltip-append-to-body': true,
      'tooltip-class': 'tooltip-wrapper'
    });
    $compile(element)($scope);
};
```

After compilation, the directive is not there in DOM. I want to understand the reason why it's not getting rendered. There are no errors in console.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not exactly duplicate but helpful I guess: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26541864/how-do-i-create-an-angularjs-tooltip-directive-with-a-compiled-template

Answer (score 0):

I've done recently something similar using "uib-tooltip-template", put all your html code inside the template and it will work just fine.

You just need to create a html file with your directive inside and asign it via $scope to the tooltip.